# Writing code for calculating Cmax and Tmax of Concentration_Time data

Tags: r, do-while, dplyr

I have a concentration-time data of many individuals. I want to find out the Cmax (maximum concentration) and Tmax (the time at Cmax) for each individual. I want to retain the results in R by adding a new "Cmax" and "Tmax" columns to the original dataset.

The data frame looks like this:

```
#df <- 
ID TIME CONC 
1   0    0
1   1    10
1   2    15
1   5    12
2   1     5 
2   2     10
2   5     20
2   6     10
```

Ans so on. I started with something to find Cmax for an individual but its not getting me any where. Any help in fixing the code or an easier way of finding both (Cmax, and Tmax) is highly appreciable !

```
 Cmax=function(df) {
 n = length(df$CONC)  
 c_temp=0  # this is a temporary counter
 c_max=0   

for(i in 2:n){  
  if(df$CONC[i] > df$CONC[i-1]{ 
  c_temp= c_temp+1   
  if(c_temp > c_max) c_max=c_temp  # check  
 } 
 }

return(c_max)  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     group_by(ID) %>% 
     mutate(Cmax= max(CONC), Tmax=TIME[which.max(CONC)])         

#   ID TIME CONC Cmax Tmax
#1  1    0    0   15    2
#2  1    1   10   15    2
#3  1    2   15   15    2
#4  1    5   12   15    2
#5  2    1    5   20    5
#6  2    2   10   20    5
#7  2    5   20   20    5
#8  2    6   10   20    5
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, c("Cmax", "Tmax") := list(max(CONC),
                          TIME[which.max(CONC)]), by=ID]
```

Or using `split` from `base R`

```
unsplit(lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(x) 
                 within(x, {Cmax <- max(CONC)
                            Tmax <- TIME[which.max(CONC)] })),
                                    df$ID)
#  ID TIME CONC Tmax Cmax
#1  1    0    0    2   15
#2  1    1   10    2   15
#3  1    2   15    2   15
#4  1    5   12    2   15
#5  2    1    5    5   20
#6  2    2   10    5   20
#7  2    5   20    5   20
#8  2    6   10    5   20
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), TIME = c(0L, 
 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L), CONC = c(0L, 10L, 15L, 12L, 5L, 
 10L, 20L, 10L)), .Names = c("ID", "TIME", "CONC"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Appreciated ! I like the dplyr package.